# How to find the eigen values of this matrix:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to find the eigen values of this matrix:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}5&1&1&1&1&1\\1&5&1&1&1&1\\1&1&5&1&1&1\\1&1&1&4&1&1\\1&1&1&1&3&0\\1&1&1&1&0&4\end{bmatrix}$$.

Since the characteristic equation is of $\deg 6$ ,I am unable to solve it by hand.

Is there any special technique to solve it?

Please help.

Comment: @Moo I got this ,I don't know if it is the same as yours $x^6 - 26x^5 + 267x^4 - 1402x^3 + 3992x^2 - 5856x + 3456$

Comment: @Moo I think there is some problem in your computation because only one co-efficient is matching;Can you recheck

Comment: According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=characteristic+polynomial+%7B%7B5,1,1,1,1,1%7D,%7B1,5,1,1,1,1%7D,%7B1,1,5,1,1,1%7D,%7B1,1,1,4,1,1%7D,%7B1,1,1,1,3,0%7D,%7B1,1,1,1,0,4%7D%7D), your calculation is not 100% exact.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial should be $x^6-26x^5+266x^4-1389x^3+3929x^2-5720x+3344$

Comment: I suggest trying to find some eigenvectors by looking at various linear combinations of the columns of $A$. For instance, subtracting the second from the first produces $(4,-4,0,0,0,0)^T$ so $(1,-1,0,0,0,0)^T$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $4$. That will let you reduce the degree of the polynomial equation to be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polynomial is:

$$x^{6}-26x^{5}+266x^{4}-1389x^{3}+3929x^{2}-5720x+3344=0$$

Which splits into:

$$(x-4)^{2}(x^{4}-18x^{3}+106x^{2}-253x+209)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

The sum of diagonal elements is the Sum of Eigenvalues .

The determinant of the matrix  is the Product of Eigenvalues.

I think this might help to some extent .

https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.adelaide.edu.au/mathslearning/system/files/media/documents/2020-03/evalue-magic-tricks-handout.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjFptDK1OXyAhVGwjgGHc08D7YQFnoECAMQBg&usg=AOvVaw2HQKn9fvrXfXNDbb9sOnKN

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.